# How to test satisfiability of logical condition programatically?

Tags: php, algorithm, logic

*$conditions* are generated programmatically using possible combinations like

```
A>B
A>B AND B=C
A>C AND C<B
A<B AND B<C AND A<C
etc etc
```

All the above 3 examples are valid. However, certain conditions such as

```
A<B AND B<C AND C<A
```

can never be true for any given value of A,B,C.

We humans can determine that the condition above will never be true.
But How to do it programmatically using PHP/MySql/VB.NET/JavaScript?

Comment: @Dagon : yes I think we do not care about the mysql part nor the languages, we are just looking for an algorithm

Comment: @Dagon http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9980412#9980412

Comment: Do you want to only generate "valid" conditions (the ones with at least the possibility to find records) or do you have a set of conditions that you want to validate?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽, set of conditions to validate :)

Comment: It truly is a shame that people are downvoting this. +1 from me.

Comment: "NEVER EXCEPTED THIS FROM THIS COMMUNITY!" that's because you are new :-)

Comment: Anyway, as a constructive comment: The term you are looking for is "satisfiability" not "valid". Should help in googling.

Comment: PDF solution: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.53.7614%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=Y0e6UbOuLpOn4APf34DYAg&usg=AFQjCNHH6Vrpe6jKHd_68pQaDGlHoEWDOA&bvm=bv.47883778,d.dmg&cad=rja

Comment: ya, i saw one in python. But couldn't find any for php

Comment: That sounds like pertinent information that should have gone in your question.

Comment: ya, its smiliar. But i'm unable to understand the paper. hmmmm...i better delete the question . i was actually searching for an inbuilt function... Anyways, thank you @JoeFrambach :)

Comment: Well, there is a way. Don't delete just yet.

Comment: okay, i'll let it be here for a few days, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Like promised, [here](http://ideone.com/POzANL)'s what I came up with. Note that it doesn't work well, it's just an idea ...

Comment: @HamZa, thank u so much. Your code is really good. Just one doubt, "A>B AND A=C AND B=C" is suppose to be false, right? its showing true.

Comment: @HamZa, somewhere '=' should be transformed to '==' before the eval I think

Comment: yup, by changine "=" to "==" gives me "true". Yet again "A>B AND B==C" gives "false" which is suppose to b "true". Well, i'm trying to recode so that i don't have to face the problem of validation.... :/

Answer (score 2):

Ok so we start somewhere, I try a basic solution. Correct me if I'm wrong.
If you have only tree columns, You can manually list the 27 seven possibilities and a example of solution that satisfies the condition if it exists

```
A=B and A=C and B=C 1,1,1  
A=B and A=C and B<C No  
A=B and A=C and B>C No  
A=B and A<C and B=C No  
A=B and A<C and B<C No  
A=B and A<C and B>C No  
A=B and A>C and B=C No  
A<B and A=C and B=C No  
...
A<B and A<C and B=C 1,2,2  
...
A>B and A>C and B>C No
```

Then you create a second table 'possibles' with all the possible responses

```
A,B,C
1,1,1
1,2,2
...
```

Now for every $condition, you simply test against the table possibles

SELECT count(*) FROM possibles WHERE $condition

If the result is >= 1, then you know your condition is valid

Comment: That's a really simple nice idea! yes, for just 3 column its definitely a good way. However, the columns can get more (depending on further progress of the current project, it may go upto 20)

Comment: This is `O(n^n)` space and time. I wouldn't wish this upon my worst enemy.

Comment: Of course that was a solution for 3 columns. Not possible for up to twenty